# How to update an object in a c# HashSet?

Tags: c#, linq, list, hashset

I'm trying to update an object in a HashSet with a different object. In the following code sample, why isn't the person2 object being updated?

```
HashSet<Person> myHash = new HashSet<Person>();

//populate the HashSet with two Person objects
var person1 = new Person() { Id=1, Name = "John", Age = 21};
var person2 = new Person() { Id=2, Name = "Lisa", Age = 25 };    
myHash.Add(person1);
myHash.Add(person2);

var person2Updated = new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "LisaUpdated", Age = 25 };    
var existingPerson2 = myHash.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 2);
existingPerson2 = person2Updated;

//why isn't the following returning person with Name "LisaUpdated"?
//It is actually returning person with Name "Lisa"
var test = myHash.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how reference types work. You have two references to `person2` object, one from your `HashSet` and one from `existingPerson2`. All

```
existingPerson2 = person2Updated;
```

does is change what `existingPerson2` points to. It doesn't change what `HashSet` points to.

Answer (score 4):

what you are doing is replacing the reference of `existingPerson2` to another one which is `person2Updated`

you are not changing the `HashSet` reference

to do what you want, you have to remove it from the hashset then add the new one

```
        myHash.Remove(existingPerson2);
        myHash.Add(person2Updated);
```

or if you want to only update the name, you can do

```
        existingPerson2.Name = person2Updated.Name
```

Comment: This is the way if you need to make a new reference that changes something but still computes equally to the previous reference. I would like to see HashSet add a Replace method that is more optimized internally someday...

Answer (score 1):

As MacinJuraszek said you are just changing to what the existingPerson2 instance is pointing to. If you want to update the hash set you will need to remove the old object from it and add the new one:

```
myHash.Remove(existingPerson2);
myHash.Add(person2updated);
```

Other option is just change the properties of the existing person to match the new values, but you take into account that anyone referencing that object will see the same changes:

```
existingPerson2.Name = "LisaUpdated";
```

Answer (score 1):

As Marcin points out, collections store references to, and not copies of, any reference types contained within.

Since the original reference `person2` and the second object added to the hashset reference the same object, any mutation to one reference to an object will reflect in all other references, e.g. simply applying:

```
person2.Name = "LisaUpdated";
```

Will also affect the object in the Hashset.